# Cannot click on the checkbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am on the page: https://m.mister-auto.com/panier ( with a product added )
I would like to click on the checkbox but it does not work:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*div[@class='col'][2]/h4")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, please provide html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added extra circular bracket after beginning quotation mark and you have added `*` and tag name both after `//`.

Please use below syntax having correct `xpath`:

Correct xpath : `//div[@class='col'][2]//h4`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col'][2]//h4")).click();
```